# Find the coordinates of p(x) relative to the basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help computing the coordinates of $p(x) = 2 - x + x^2 + 4x^3$ relative to the standard basis ${1, x, x^2, x^3}$, and also relative to the basis $B = {1 - x + x^2, 1 + x - 2x^2, 3 + x - x^2 + x^3, 4 - x^3}$, however, I think that I should be able to figure out the other if I am guided through one.

I know that I should should somehow get a system of equations from these polynomials, find the RREF, and that should be the answer, but I am unsure of how to begin. I have tried to Google several similar questions online, but none of them make sense to me.

Following dxiv's advice -

I set up the equations

$2 - x + x^2 + 4x^3 = (a)(1 - x + x^2) + (b)(1 + x - 2x^2) + (c)(3 + x - x^2) + (d)(4 - x^3)$.

Then, I compared coefficients and was lead to the system of equations

$a + b + 3c + 4d = 2$

$-a + b + c = -1$

$a - 2b - c = 1$

$c-d = 4$

Solving the system of equations gives me:

$a = \frac{-1}{8}$, $b = -2$, $c = \frac{23}{8}$, and $d = \frac{-9}{8}$.

Does this mean that the coordinates relative to $p(x)$ to this basis is equal to

$\begin{bmatrix}
    -1/4 \\
    -2 \\  
    23/9 \\
    -9/8  
\end{bmatrix}$ ?

and for the standard basis ${1, x, x^2, x^3}$, the coordinate is just the vector [2, -1, 1, 4]?

Comment: Can you at least do the first part?

Comment: Go back to basic definitions. What does it mean for an $n$-tuple of scalars to be the coordinates of a vector in a given basis?

Comment: Hint: $\,2-x+x^2+4x^3 = a(1-x+x^2)+b(1+x-2x^2)+c(3+x-x^2)+d(4-x^3)\,$. Collect terms in powers of $x\,$, then identify the coefficients and solve the system of linear equations for $a,b,c,d\,$.

Comment: `help computing the coordinates` $a,b,c,d$ *are* the coordinates relative to basis $B\,$, so you're done.

Comment: can you please check my work in a few minutes  ?

Comment: I finished.  Is what I have done correct ?

Comment: `(c)(3+x−x^2)` That's missing the $x^3$ term, it should be $c(3+x−x^2+x^3)\,$. I can see that my previous comment happened to be missing that same term, but that doesn't make it right.

Comment: I updated it my post.

Comment: `and for the standard basis ...` Technically it's the same, you solve $2-x+x^2+4x^3=a\cdot 1 + b\cdot x + c\cdot x^2 + d\cdot x^3$ for $a,b,c,d\,$, but the solution is *not* $1,1,1,1\,$.

Comment: it is <2, -1, 1, 4>. I did not look too carefully at it. this is correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And the other one will be correct, too, once you solve the right system.